# Url of background downloads in Windows

Tags: windows, networking, monitoring

I'm trying to monitor my network connections. In the background, some downloads are running.

I'm aware of the `netstat` command. But is there a way to see the actual url, from which the file in background is being downloaded? I'm using windows 10.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can use URL Snooper , it will show all downloads in your network from whom with their URL's 
its based on Pcap/WinPcap
you can understand more here : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_Snooper